# How can I change Canvas at RecycleViewer?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-recyclerview

I have RecycleViewer with Canvas view in list item. How can I change backgrouncolor of Canvas view in my RecycleViewerAdapter ?

Below is my onBindViewHolder method in my RecycleViewerAdapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.openprice.setText(mopenPrice.get(position));

//How can I change backgrouncolor canvas view ????

}
```

my ViewHolder

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        openprice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.openprice);            
        viewx = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewx);



    }
```

itemlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@drawable/border_listfavorite"
>

<view class="com.eusecom.exforu.MyView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:id="@+id/viewx"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/opentxt"
    android:text="@string/opentxt"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewx"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/openprice"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/opentxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewx"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MyView.java

```
public class MyView extends View {
public MyView(Context cxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(cxt, attrs);
    setMinimumHeight(100);
    setMinimumWidth(100);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas cv) {
    cv.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.setStrokeWidth(5);
    cv.drawLine(20, 0, 20, cv.getHeight(), p);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use invalidate() method for calling onDraw method.

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.viewx.setText(mopenPrice.get(position));

    if(condition){
          holder.viewx.setCustomColor(Color.GREEN);
          holder.viewx.invalidate();
    }

    }
```

public class MyView extends View {

```
private int color = Color.WHITE;

public MyView(Context cxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(cxt, attrs);
    setMinimumHeight(100);
    setMinimumWidth(100);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas cv) {
    cv.drawColor(color);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.setStrokeWidth(5);
    cv.drawLine(20, 0, 20, cv.getHeight(), p);
}

public void setCustomColor(int color){
   this.color = color;
}


public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    private MyView viewx;
    super(itemView);
    openprice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.openprice);            
    viewx = (MyView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewx);

}
```

Comment: It looks good but i need to change color of viewx and this is view how to see in my  itemlist.xml and ViewHolder. How can i hold this viewx in my ViewHolder ? The method setCustomColor(int) is undefined for the type View

Comment: Anyway "viewx" is instanceof MyView, so u can typecast it and use ? see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks everything is OK.